# jQuery code at Drupal page not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, drupal

I've tried coming up with a solution as to why the following jQuery script does not work. It works in all other browsers but IE?

I've done a script (see below) which has been added inside a drupal page.

```
    <script>

    (function ($) {

    $.get("showinfo.php", function (data) { 
       data = '"' + data + '"';    
       $("#siteloader").html(data);
       var newHTML = $('#siteloader').html();
       $('#siteloader').html(newHTML.substr(1,newHTML.length-2));
       var scrollHeightData = $('#siteloader').height();
       $('#siteloader').css("height", scrollHeightData);
    });  


    }(jQuery));

    </script>
    <div id="siteloader"></div>
```

---

Tried the following, which also works in other browsers:

```
    $.get('showinfo.php', null, function(html) {
       $('#siteloader').replaceWith(html);
       $('#siteloader').html(html);
       var scrollHeightData = $('#siteloader').height();
       $('#siteloader').css("height", scrollHeightData);
    });
```

Do you know if this can be done so it works in IE?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no access to test your code in IE. But there's what looks like a typo in your code on the last line in your javascript code.

It should be a self-calling function, so the part `(jQuery)` should go after the closing bracket.

```
<script>
(function ($) {

$.get("showinfo.php", function (data) { 
   data = '"' + data + '"';    
   $("#siteloader").html(data);
   var newHTML = $('#siteloader').html();
   $('#siteloader').html(newHTML.substr(1,newHTML.length-2));
   var scrollHeightData = $('#siteloader').height();
   $('#siteloader').css("height", scrollHeightData);
});  


})(jQuery); // instead of "}(jQuery));"
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. That seemed to do the trick :) thanks. Another issue was that the version of IE was quite old, so it didn't load/call the .get command.

Comment: Right. In some IE browsers it still does not work? As if the .get function doesn't load. Even when upgrading to a new version of IE? It's quite strange?